# HP AMD Driver does not stick

Tags: windows-10, drivers, graphics-card

I installed a fresh Windows 10 64-bit, and everything works except the video driver. There are 3 video drivers to choose from, the Windows Generic video driver, the AMD driver 1, and the AMD driver 2 that I manually downloaded from the HP site. The generic driver works well, and the HP/AMD driver that I manually downloaded works well too. I can go to Device Manager, uninstall the problematic driver #2 and also delete the driver, and then I can use either the driver #1, or driver #3, and it works well, until I restart. When I restart, Windows automatically reverts back to the driver #2 that works very poorly. The symptoms from driver 2 is it freezes every 3 seconds, stays frozen for 1 seconds, then thaws for 3 seconds, then freezes again. I have definitely isolated the problem to the driver, it is not a PC slowness issue, and it is not a virus.

How can I permanently select a driver, and reinstall as many times as needed without the system switching a different video driver?

Answer (score 0):

If the vendor (HP) has supplied a working driver to the Microsoft Catalogue, then that (Microsoft Catalogue) should be the best one to use. HP will tailor the driver to your model of machine.

(There are about 16 Million combinations of drivers and computer types/models in the database, so it is a good repository of good drivers for you).

Delete the other two drivers (as they will not take precedence over the Microsoft Catalogue) and just use the one driver Windows supplies this way.

Drivers I get for my machine that have been supplied to the catalogue work very well.

Comment: It doesn't matter what driver I choose, because after I install a new driver, and then restart, it will revert back to a bad driver automatically. Doesn't matter if I delete the old driver. Doesn't matter how many times I delete and restart.

Please carefully re-read my entire paragraph and try to understand the question. The title of this issue is "driver does not stick". You can read that too. Thank you.

Comment: The driver from the Microsoft Catalogue should stick. Try updating the BIOS and Chipset (if there is a chipset driver) and then try updating from the catalogue again. You may need to call HP Support for assistance with drivers.